# Sql query to find out sum against individual id

Tags: mysql, sql, database, xampp, relational-database

Suppose I have table like:

name: table_money

[image]

I need a sql query that produces the following result containing sum of money for each id.

[image: a]

How can I find out the total money of an individual id?

What is the SQL query?

Comment: Check out `GROUP BY`, combined with `SUM`.

Comment: select id,sum(money) from table_money group by id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the sum for each ID you need to group the results by the `id` column and apply the `SUM` aggregate function to the `money` column.

```
SELECT id, SUM(money) 
FROM table_money
GROUP BY id
```

You can read more about grouping of SQL results here:

> - [Group by two columns and display grand total in every row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848886/sql-server-group-by-sum-function)
> - [Having Sums, Averages, and Other Grouped Data *by Oracle Magazine*](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/issue-archive/2013/13-jan/o13sql-1886636.html)
> - [GROUP BY (Transact-SQL) *on MSDN*](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177673.aspx)