# SQL Grouping for the below example

Tags: sql, grouping

I have a table as shown in the picture. how can i write  an sql to gete the result as i have mentioned in the "Expected REsult"

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Group by two columns and display grand total in every row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17848886/group-by-two-columns-and-display-grand-total-in-every-row)

Comment: how did you decide to choose SUB1 and not SUB2 in REFERENCE=A? what if the date for reference=A are different? which one to select?

Comment: You should explain why that is your expected result. Don't expect readers to have to guess how the input maps to the output; it's a waste of time and may only produce correct answers for some example data. Also, data should be included as formatted text tables, not images.

Comment: i have edited the question with new image. that is my actual requirement

Comment: Please specify database you're using in tags.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557 and the accepted answer

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add the tag for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `db2`, `sql-server`, ...

Answer (score 0):

Please check following SQL Select statement

```
select distinct
reference, 
first_value(subject) over (partition by reference, subject order by date), 
sum(mark1) over (partition by reference, subject), 
sum(mark2) over (partition by reference, subject), 
date
from actualdata
```

But there are many unresolved issues here,
First of all, SUB2 is lost somehow
To get SUB1 I used [SQL first_value function](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/first_value-sql-analytic-function-in-sql-server-2012.aspx) but what defines which is first and other comes next is not clear.
And I only partitioned data according to reference.
Maybe we should add more columns here, like Date?

Comment: i have edited my question again, please find the new image

Comment: Wilson, I also updated the solution, please check it if it works for you